# Fluent NHibernate - How map an IList<Enum> as list of strings

Tags: list, enums, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class with `IList<Role> roles` as a property which is mapped by the following code:

```cs
 map.HasMany(u=>u.roles).Element("role").Cascade.All()
```

but this maps `roles` to a column of `int` but I want it to be mapped to a column of `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the override to specify the NHibernate.Type explicitly

```
.Element("role", e => e.Type<NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType<Role>>())
```

Comment: This throws an Exception. I add `Role` as the generic type and used it as `e => e.Type<NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType<Role>>` and it works. Thanks.