# NHibernate: map collection of enums using string and store as nvarchar

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums, fluent-nhibernate

I have an enum type:

```
public enum CommunicationType
{
    [Description("Callback to client")]
    Callback
}
```

Which one use as a property of `IList<CommunicationType>` in class `Partner`:

```
public class Partner
{       
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CommunicationType> CommunicationTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My `PartnerMap` class looks like this:

```
public class PartnerMap : ClassMap<Partner>
{
    public PartnerMap()
    {
        Schema("tm");
        Table("Partner");

        Id(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.CommunicationTypes)
            .Schema("tm")
            .Table("PartnerCommunicationType")
            .KeyColumn("PartnerId")
            .Element("CommunicationType");
    }
}
```

One to many relation between `Partner` and `CommunicationType` i store in table `[tm].[PartnerCommunicationType]`:

```
PartnerId bigint
CommunicationType nvarchar(256)
```

**What's my final goal**: to store enums as nvarchar value and map it from table to `IList<CommunicationType>` from column `CommunicationType` of table `[tm].[PartnerCommunicationTypes`.

**What's my problem**: String was in incorrect format.

[image]

I tried to map `CommunicationType` as single property using `Map(x=>x.CommunicationType)` and this works great, but i can't do that with collection.

Is there a way i could map collection of enums and map it from nvarchar?

**Edit:** this answer should help me `http://stackoverflow.com/a/22732415/2524304` but i can't understand how could i set type using FluentNHibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer: [Fluent NHibernate - How map an IList<Enum> as list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597088/fluent-nhibernate-how-map-an-ilistenum-as-list-of-strings)

You have to use `NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType<T>` with your type as generic:

```
HasMany(x => x.CommunicationTypes)
  .Schema("tm")
  .Table("PartnerCommunicationType")
  .KeyColumn("PartnerId")
  .Element("CommunicationType", part => part.Type<EnumStringType<CommunicationType>>());
```